# How to use VBScript to lock a specific region of a Word document?

Tags: ms-word, vbscript

So I want to make a specific part of a Word document read-only using VBScript.
The version of Word I am using is from Office 16.
How to do this manually (recorded a macro for this to see if I would get a better idea on how to do this) I found [here](https://www.simuldocs.com/blog/how-to-lock-parts-of-a-document-in-microsoft-word).

I know how to lock the entire document, and know that the following works:

```
'Protect Document 
objDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading, True, "password"
```

I saw [this question being asked](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca266a18-1f24-41d9-91fd-b20c50c15892/can-i-use-vbscript-to-protect-only-part-of-a-word-document?forum=innovateonoffice) (on an old MS forum), but nothing more than this.
Any help with this sort of issue on an example I would appreciate.

Comment: The [`Protect()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.protect) does not support protecting part of a document. What you are trying to do cannot be done programmatically using the Word Object Model. The supported protection types are listed in the [`WdProtectionType` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdprotectiontype).

Comment: Okay, did not know that. Thanks for the heads-up.
Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Having said that did you try the solution in the MS Forum question `objWord.Selection.Editors.Add(-1)  ' -1 = everyone` to make an exception? The suggestion is by setting the `Editors` on a `Selection` to "everyone" that `Selection` becomes unprotected.

Answer (score 0):

While you [can't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73715370/how-to-use-vbscript-to-lock-a-specific-region-of-a-word-document#comment130170203_73715370) using the [`Protect()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.protect) directly the answer appears to be in the [Question you linked](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca266a18-1f24-41d9-91fd-b20c50c15892/can-i-use-vbscript-to-protect-only-part-of-a-word-document?forum=innovateonoffice) from the MS Forum.

```vb
' Protect Document
objDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading, True, "password"

' Select last paragraph of the document
objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Select 

' Make an exception for current selection
objWord.Selection.Editors.Add(-1)  ' -1 = everyone
```

Using the [`Selection` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection) you can modify the `Editors` on a protected document selection to "everyone" which unprotects that selection only leaving the rest of the document still protected.